# Maintaining state within a recursive function in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, state, sortedmap

I have a recursive function that spits out a hash every time it is called.

The first time it loops around the hash is:

```
{1 "mary", 2 "dean"}
```

next round spits out

```
{23 "ava", 4 "scout"}
```

and the final round returns

```
 {3 "bina", 16 "bob"}
```

My function will always return the last round of data, {3 "gina", 16 "bob"}. 
I'd like to, instead of spitting out the last piece of data, store them all in one giant hash so that I can compare them.  After I compare them, the function should return "ava", because that is the value associated with the highest key.  What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: What did you try? Show us some code please.

Answer (score 1):

One general pattern is to add a state argument to your recursive function and provide an arity of the funciton that adds the initial state value. Then in the base case you can do postprocessing of the state value.

Here is an example that builds a map of inputs before the first odd number to a random value:

```
user> (defn example
        ([input] (example input {}))  ;; one argument recurs with default value
        ([input state]                ;; two arg case passes the state.
           (if (odd? (first input))
             state
             (recur (rest input)
                    (assoc state (first input) (rand-int 10))))))
#'user/example
```

And one that selects the highest value form the resulting state:

```
user> (example [2 4 8 9])
{8 0, 4 1, 2 4}
user> (defn example
        ([input] (example input {}))
        ([input state]
            (if (odd? (first input))
             (first (sort-by val state))
             (recur (rest input)
                    (assoc state (first input) (rand-int 10))))))
#'user/example
user> (example [2 4 8 9])
[8 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a side-effective function that spits out a sequence of values, model it as a sequence. If the sequence terminates, presumably the function then returns an invalid value.

The function

```
(defn ensequence [f! valid?]
  (take-while valid? (repeatedly f!)))
```

... returns the sequence of values produced by side-effective function `f!`, terminating whenever the `valid?` test fails.

For instance,

```
(ensequence #(rand-int 10) #(not= 5 %))
```

... returns a sequence of random values in `(range 10)`, stopping just before the first `5`:

```
(6 9)
```

... for instance (your milage *will* vary).

To show how `ensequence` works in your case, we use an inverse function that turns a sequence into a function that returns its successive elements, and `nil` thereafter:

```
(defn oracle! [coll]
  (let [s (atom coll)]
    (fn [] (let [x (first @s)] (swap! s rest) x))))
```

For example,

```
(repeatedly 10 (oracle! (range 5)))
;(0 1 2 3 4 nil nil nil nil nil)
```

For your data

```
(def data [{1 "mary", 2 "dean"} {23 "ava", 4 "scout"} {3 "bina", 16 "bob"}])
```

The function

```
(oracle! data)
```

... successively returns its elements, followed by `nil`s:

```
(repeatedly 10 (oracle! data))
;({1 "mary", 2 "dean"} {23 "ava", 4 "scout"} {3 "bina", 16 "bob"}
   nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
```

We can use `ensequence` on this, however it was generated, to recover the original sequence:

```
(ensequence (oracle! data) identity)
;({1 "mary", 2 "dean"} {23 "ava", 4 "scout"} {3 "bina", 16 "bob"})
```

Since `nil` is false and never valid here, `identity` is a good validity test.

Now that we have the sequence, we can do whatever we like with it. In your case, we just

- concatenate the maps into a big sequence of map-entries;
- find the entry with maximum `key`; and
- take its `val`.

Thus:

```
(val (apply max-key key (reduce concat data)))
;"ava"
```

We should use `(ensequence (oracle! data) identity)` instead of the equivalent `data`, but it doesn't make any difference.